# Add timestamp and username to log

Tags: python, django, logging

I have setup Logging inside my settings.py, and I want to know if it's possible to add to the error log line - Which user experienced the error and a timestamp for the issue. Is this possible?

Current code

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can add formatters and use them in your handlers. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) is a list of available default attributes you can add, e.g. a timestamp with `{asctime}`. To add the user, you'd have to supply it in the logging call as an extra argument as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug).

```
LOGGING = {
    'formatters': {
        'timestamp': {
            'format': '{asctime} {levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'timestamp'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on startup. I'm using uwsgi + nginx to run the server

`--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---`

Comment: Don't know how this could come from defining values in a dictionary in your settings.py.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a [formatter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#formatters) for the log, for example:

```
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
        'style': '{',
    }
},
```

To log the user that experiences the error you would have to pass the username in the message, for example in your view:

```
def my_view(request):
    logger.error('View error for user {}'.format(request.user.username))
```

Comment: This means I would have to manually add points in my code that if something happens then log this error. I currently do not have it at this point. I would like it to automatically write the error the system noticed and just add the user and a timestamp to that error.

Comment: That's the only way I can think of to log the user experiencing the error. Here is a list of the attributes recorded by the logger https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Answer (score 3):

```
'formatters': {
         'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s; %(name)s] Message "%(message)s" from %
(pathname)s:%(lineno)d in %(funcName)s',
             'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
}
```

You can add new formatter with above format. it should be able to log line no. but to log username, I don't think of any other ways than manually doing it.